# Is it fine to use vue's computed property to transform a promise?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `Ref<Promise<any[]>>` attribute. This attribute is updated with a new promise when something happens (for example a new search)

This attribute is used as input to another component that renders the resolved promise. The prop in the component, expects a `Ref<Promise<any[]>> value.`

I am using promises, because it's a nice and natural way to have several states. Loading, Empty, Data and Error, and the component can display correctly those states with just one prop.

But sometimes, the response from backend is not exactly what I need. For example, I need it sorted and the server returns the values in random order.

What I tried is to use a computed that reacts to the change in the promise attribute and returns a new promise that transforms the value as needed.

Something like this (bare with me, because it's something like pseudo code)

```
const items$ = ref<Promise<any[]>>(Promise.resolve([]);
const sortedItems$ = computed(() => items.value.then(i -> [...i].sort()));
```

As far as I know and tested, it works. But I am getting a linter error that says that I should not do async computation in computed properties.

I understand that in the async code, any access to reactive properties will not be tracked. So in the few cases that I need another reactive property to transform the promise I do it sync... for example:

```
const items$ = ref<Promise<any[]>>(Promise.resolve([]);
const order = ref('ASC');

const sortedItems$ = computed(() => {
    const justForTracking = order.value;
    items.value.then(i -> [...i].sort(justForTracking))
});
```

Then again, it works. And whenever order or items$ change, the computed is re-evaluated and a new promise is returned.

As I think about it, I am just transforming a promise into another promise, and doesn't care too much about the value of the promise. And to transform a value into another value is the whole idea of computed.

But the presence of the error makes me feel that I am doing something wrong. I can ignored it but my colleges don't like it. (as I don't like when I see that someone is turning off the linter errors / warnings)

So my question is.... is it wrong to do what I am doing? Should I use Watch and another Ref instead? is this just an overzealous warning? *why is it an error?*

### Example of what I am doing

```
<script>
const input = ref(Promise.resolve('lowercase')
const output = computed(() => input.value.then(s => s. toUpperCase());
</script>
```

Note, I am not expecting output to be a string. I expect it to be a promise. I am failing to see how I am against any of the recommendations.

I am seeking confirmation that this is a valid use of a computed and it doesn't go against sensible recommendations.

Comment: *"You'll need to convert the computed property into a piece of data. Whenever that data needs to change, you'll call a method that will make the Ajax call and update that data once its done.* This taken from a long article I strongly advise: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/vue/async-computed

Comment: That's not my case. In that example they try to return a list of items that is retrieved asynchronously from the server. That won't work because they changed the return type of the computed, from an array to a promise<array>

In my case.. the piece of data *is the promise* (not the value resolved by the promise) (i am watching a promise... and returning another, derived, promise) and everything works allright.. it just that the linter mark it as an error.

And I am having trouble understanding why it is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the official Vue Docs:

> ## Best Practices
>
> ### Getters should be side-effect free
>
> It is important to remember that computed getter functions **should only perform pure computation**
> and be free of side effects. For example, don't make async requests or
> mutate the DOM inside a computed getter! Think of a computed property
> as declaratively describing how to derive a value based on other
> values - its only responsibility should be computing and returning
> that value. Later in the guide we will discuss how we can perform side
> effects in reaction to state changes with watchers.
>
> ### Avoid mutating computed value
>
> The returned value from a computed property is derived state. Think of
> it as a temporary snapshot - every time the source state changes, a
> new snapshot is created. **It does not make sense to mutate a snapshot,
> so a computed return value should be treated as read-only and never be
> mutated** - instead, update the source state it depends on to trigger
> new computations.

AND

> Computed properties allow us to declaratively compute derived values.
> However, there are cases where we need to perform "side effects" in
> reaction to state changes - for example, mutating the DOM, or **changing
> another piece of state based on the result of an async operation.**

So the best practice is to use watchers instead whenever you want to mutate you computed value. A basic example can also be found on the official docs.

### Basic Example

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const question = ref('')
const answer = ref('Questions usually contain a question mark. ;-)')

// watch works directly on a ref
watch(question, async (newQuestion, oldQuestion) => {
  if (newQuestion.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    answer.value = 'Thinking...'
    try {
      const res = await fetch('https://yesno.wtf/api')
      answer.value = (await res.json()).answer
    } catch (error) {
      answer.value = 'Error! Could not reach the API. ' + error
    }
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <p>
    Ask a yes/no question:
    <input v-model="question" />
  </p>
  <p>{{ answer }}</p>
</template>
```

​

#### References

- https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed
- https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't think this is what I am doing. I am not changing anything outside the computed so there is no side-effects. Nor I am mutating any value. I am just calculating a derived state. It just happens that the input value is a promise, and the output value is another, derived, promise.

Comment: In your basic example, you are doing a side effect You are doing a fetch inside the watch and your input data is a ref string. Imagine that the input is a promise string. and the output is just a promise that returns the resolved value of the input promise iin uppercase.